# Writing to a file with existing information in it, and to insert line by line, each is has multiple items separated with a ';'

Tags: java, file

I am trying to write the information into a textfile after the user has input all their fields.
My text file have a already some information in it.

> Anthony Ducan;anthony;a123;55 Peter Street;3321444;VISA;3213504011223
>   Barry Blake;barry;a999;456 George Street;23239876;VISA;435677779876
>   Claire Rerg;clare;c678;925 Edward
>   Lane;67893344;MASTERCARD;223344556677

I want to enter them into as a string into my textfile, and each line has multiple items seprated by `;`.

Do I need to open my file , read what it contains before adding new information , or I can just simply add into it?

I have set up a constructor for inputting values, but how do I use it? Do i need to make a new method for my main to call it?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class newCust{

    String name,username,password,address,contact,creditType,creditNum;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public newCust(String name , String username, String password, String address, String contact, String creditType, String creditNum){

    this.name= name;
    this.username= username;
    this.password = password;
    this.address = address;
    this.contact = contact;
    this.creditType = creditType;
    this.creditNum = creditNum;
    System.out.println("Welcome to Kreg Hotel Booking System");
    System.out.println("==============================================");
    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter your login username: ");
    username = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter your login password: ");
    password = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter your address: ");
    address = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter your contact: ");
    contact = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter your credit card type: ");
    creditType = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter your credit card number: ");
    creditNum = input.nextLine();


        try{
            PrintWriter fileout = new PrintWriter("customerinfo");
            newCust info = new newCust(name,username,password,address,contact,creditType,creditNum);
            fileout.print(info);

        }
        catch(IOException ex){

        }


  }

    public static void main(String[] args){

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ***Do i need to open my file , read what it contains before adding new information , or i can just simply add into it?***

You can *append* to a file, but you can't insert characters or lines in the middle of it.

You can [append to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java) by using for instance `new FileWriter(file, true)`.

If this is production code and not simply an exercise for you, I recommend you to look into [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

To write to a file, you use `FileOutputStream`.

Check if there is [any constructor or methods that allows you to open the file appending to it instead of overwritting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)

Comment: By the way, that kind of files are called CSV `Comma Separated Values`. There already libraries to deal with them.